# Como retornar objeto parente de objeto?

Tags: javascript

Estou precisando retornar um objeto anterior de um objeto, isso é porque estou usando `this` em função para testes.

Veja:

```
NodeList.prototype.style={
    set background(a){
        DefStyle("background",a,this)//aqui
    },set backgroundColor(a){
        DefStyle("backgroundColor",a,this/*não era isso que eu queria :/*/)//e aqui...
    }
};
```

Esse `this` retorna o objeto/propriedade `style` de uma prototype `NodeList` (estou usando `querySelectorAll` para o teste, ele gera umas divs), mas não era essa a intenção.

O `this` atualmente retornaria um objeto com setters `background` e `backgroundColor`! Exemplo (sem usar setters):

```
{background:null,backgroundColor:null}
```

Há alguma forma <s>legal</s> de retornar o objeto parente do objeto parente desse objeto `this`, que venha antes de `prototype` (ruím saber que não parecem existir maneiras)?

Obs:

- eu quero fazer algo como `parentElement`, mas sem `DOM`, usando
  `objetos`/`propriedades`, como:
- `Objeto={Huh:null,Propriedade:null};`
- `Objeto.Propriedade.parent`, eu queria retornar `Objeto`.

Comment: Li a sua pergunta três vezes e não entendi o que você está tentando fazer. A sua pergunta é (ou parece ser) alguma coisa simples, mas você se expressa de uma maneira tão confusa que não dá para entender nada. A primeira sugestão é quanto a esse nome "*parente*". Se a ideia é traduzir o termo "*parent*" do inglês, então você fez errado, pois "*parent*" não é "*parente*" em inglês. Em inglês o termo "*parent*" é uma palavra que refere a uma pessoa que é pai ou mãe. Entretanto, mesmo assim ainda não dá para entender. Sugiro você dar mais detalhes sobre o que você está tentando fazer com isso.

Comment: Referes-te a elementos do DOM ou queres saber de que objeto um outro objeto herdou?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Eu sei disso, mas o que quero fazer é algo como `parentElement`, só que com objetos/propriedades, em JS, pelo `this` em minha prototype. :/

Comment: @Sergio Refiro-me à um `NodeList`! Eu quero pegar o objeto parente até que retorne um tal `querySelectorAll` com mais divs. Obs: Tudo que retorna `querySelectorAll` são `prototype` de `NodeList`, e são algo como arrays, embora.

Comment: Desculpem pela demora, minha mãe me mandou dormir.......

Comment: Obedeça e honre sua mãe. Bom sono.

Comment: @durtto E bom dia, dss.

Comment: Bom dia. Veja as respostas, acho que te conseguiram uma solução.

Comment: @durtto O único problema é porque as soluções tem haver com `DOM`.

Comment: Lamento mas ainda não é claro para mim. Queres sobreescrever o `prototype` com um _seter_/_getter_ teu? que permita escrever/ler o estilo e também retornar o elemento pai um elemento/node?

Comment: Eu quero aplicar um estilo para vários elementos dentro de um `NodeList` (querySelectorAll), mas sem fazer loop em linha, com a mesma cara do JS, para fazer uns testes... como: `document.querySelectorAll(".lF").style.huh=...`, e para isso preciso pegar o objeto `parente` de `this`  na `prototype` que coloquei na questão.

Answer (score 1):

Se com "parente", você quer dizer *parent* (pai). Você pode usar o `.parentNode` ou o `.parentElement`. Funcionam da seguinte maneira:

```
<div>
  <h1 id="myTitle" >Title</h1>
</div>

document.getElementById("myTitle").parentElement.nodeName // isso retorna "DIV"
```

Assim você captura o elemento *pai* do elemento em questão. Olhe abaixo:

### Exemplo

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.backgroundColor = function(color){
   this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = color
};
document.querySelectorAll('h1')[0].backgroundColor('gold');
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

No exemplo acima eu aplico a função `backgroundColor` ao `h1`, e seu *parent* a `div`, que recebe o efeito.

Os exemplos que usei não são os mesmo de seu caso devido a pergunta estar vaga, além de que seu código não é realmente um "javascript".

Comment: `parentNode` não funciona para `objetos`, huh!